# How Int8 (byte) operations can be useful for deep learning?

Tags: nvidia, deep-learning, theano

Nvidia is planing to add hardware support for int8 operations to their new titan card and target deep learning community. I am trying to understood how its useful and what types of network will benefit from this and what phase(training/inferencing etc).

I know that FP16 instead of FP32 is what should be useful for DL, but not sure how int8 could do. There are some research that you can train with full FP32 precision and then round it to one byte - but this does not speedup or reduce memory footprint for training.

They probably made this decision(to implement hardware accelartion of int8) based on some papers or research. What are these?

Comment: the pixel of most input image is `int8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reduce memory footprint and calculation overhead, a common approach (esp. for mobile) is quantization; that would then happen in integer. Read more about it here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization